# openssl EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name crashed with no information

Tags: c, openssl, visual-studio-2019

In my get_keypair function,I want to create an EC_KEY structure by `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)` .By doing so,I got a crash on my vs2019 with no details.Below comes my code.

```
bool get_keypair(EC_KEY** key, bool getcompressed,uint8_t* rawprikey,  uint8_t rawprikeylen) {
    BIGNUM* priv; //prikey bignum
    BN_CTX* ctx; //hold the operation
    const EC_GROUP* group;
    EC_POINT* pub; //pubkey point st
    *key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1); //secp256k1, !!!crashed here
    if (*key == 0) {
        printf("new ec key failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    priv = BN_new(); //create bignum
    BN_bin2bn(rawprikey, 32, priv); //fill the bigbum with prikey
    EC_KEY_set_private_key(*key, priv); //put prikey bignum to key pair

    ctx = BN_CTX_new(); //create context
    BN_CTX_start(ctx); //init context
    group = EC_KEY_get0_group(*key); //G
    pub = EC_POINT_new(group); //create pub st
    EC_POINT_mul(group, pub, priv, NULL, NULL, ctx); //P = n * G
    EC_KEY_set_public_key(*key, pub); //fill the key pair, !!!crashed here
    EC_KEY_set_conv_form(*key, getcompressed ? POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED : POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED); //compressd or not 
    uint64_t pubkeylen = i2o_ECPublicKey(*key, NULL);
    uint8_t *pubkey = calloc(pubkeylen, sizeof(uint8_t));

    uint8_t* pub_copy = pubkey;
    if (i2o_ECPublicKey(*key, &pub_copy) != pubkeylen) {
        puts("Unable to decode public key");
        return false;
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < *pubkeylen; i++) {
        printf("%02X", (*pubkey)[i]);
    }*/

    EC_POINT_free(pub);//free all
    BN_CTX_end(ctx);
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    BN_clear_free(priv);
    return true;
}
```

Just a proof of work,No checks was added.
And I keet rerun the program many times,saw that the program will crash at different code.
Below are some pictures captured when the program crashed.

[crashed at EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dteQz.png)

[crashed at EC_KEY_set_public_key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct62J.png)

[crashed on main exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3aJc.png)

[linked librares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQXv5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate "EC_KEY** key" variable before call get_keypair() function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: If you intended this to actually be an answer in shape of a rhetoric question please [edit] to rephrase into a clear statement. Ideally explain how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem.